# How does OpenVPN server assign client IP addresses in case of multiclient configuration?

Tags: ip, openvpn

For a multiclient OpenVPN configuration, as we can find from the relevant documentation (`server.conf` comments),

> Configure server mode and supply a VPN subnet for OpenVPN to draw
>   client addresses from. The server will take 10.8.0.1 for itself, the
>   rest will be made available to clients. Each client will be able to
>   reach the server on 10.8.0.1.
>
> server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0

So, as we understand, we are actually assigning a pool 256 addresses, the first usable address being 10.8.0.1 and the last usable should be 10.8.0.254. Among these, the first of the addresses (10.8.0.1) will be assigned to the server, as already made explicit in the above text.

Also, in the client configuration file, we find something like,

> The hostname/IP and port of the server. You can have multiple remote
>   entries to load balance between the servers.
>
> remote my-server-1 1194

Where, the last line, as I deduce, should be written as,

```
remote 10.8.0.1 1194
```

in order to match with the server address.

*(This statement is not correct, see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/200005/112346).)*

Now, my question is, which algorithm does the sever follow in order to assign addresses to the client from the pool of available addresses (10.8.0.2-10.8.0.254)?

Is it something like that the first client gets
the .2 address, the next one .3 address? Or is it that addresses are assigned at random? Or is it something else, if it is .5, 9., why is it like that?

Answer (score 2):

OpenVPN doesn't document the exact algorithm it uses to find free addresses in the pool because it's an implementation detail and it doesn't really matter as long as it's a free address. Nevertheless, you can see what algorithm it uses by looking at the function `ifconfig_pool_find` in `pool.c`:

- If in `duplicate_cn` mode, take the first free address.
- If the IP address previously used by the same client is still free, select it.
- Otherwise, pick the least recently used free address from the pool.

As for your other question:

```
remote 10.8.0.1 1194
```

No, you definitely shouldn't use that as the `remote` address. Since you try to reach the tunnel server through the tunnel itself and the tunnel isn't set up yet at this point (during initialization) you cannot contact the server. If you somehow could establish the tunnel, you'd then have a routing loop.

In order to establish the tunnel, you need to have an IP address on which you can contact the other endpoint of the tunnel without benefit of the tunnel. This would normally be a reachable public Internet address for that endpoint. That's what you have to give for `remote`.

Comment: So, does that mean the clients will have addresses like .2, .3 or some such as decided by the server? In some setup, why did I get .5 as the first client address?

Comment: I don't know why you got `.5` as the first address, but... why does it matter?

Comment: It mattered for me because I was wondering why .5 was assigned instead of .2. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Perhaps my ignorance shows, but your answer seems to be a bit off the track from this one, https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/273-qifconfig-poolq-option-use-a-30-subnet-4-private-ip-addresses-per-client-when-used-in-tun-mode?

Comment: Ah, I forgot about that configuration because I don't use it! I'm sorry about that. Yeah, allocating in units of /30 explains why the first address handed out would be `.5`. It also wastes 3 IP addresses per client.